# Your target project 'XXX' doesn't reference EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

This happen when I try to use Migration in PMC. This is the only project I have in my solution and I have installed everything. Can someone help me with this, please?
[image]

Comment: Are you using several separate projects in your solution?!

Comment: @Hamed Moghadasi No. I figure out what happen. The version of EntityFramework Core I'm using it's too high. After switching back to 2.2.0, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The version of EntityFramework Core I'm using it's too high. After switching back to 2.2.0, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. I just used `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration` command for it to work.